# Hand luggage storage in Barcelona, or better to take with us?

Tags: spain, hand-luggage, barcelona

I will be visiting Barcelona for 5 days with a small cabin trolley. On the last day we need to check out from our apartment at 10, but the flight won't be until 4. We'd like to go somewhere for lunch in the mean time. Are there any public spaces where we can safely store our luggage? Or would it be more convenient to just take the trolleys with us?

Will restaurants be annoyed by the luggage we bring, even if it is relatively small?

The apartment does not offer luggage storage and we'd prefer to stay in the city center before we head to the airport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of left luggage places in Barcelona city centre - one example is that there are luggage lockers at the Estació del Nord bus terminal, next to Arc de Triomf (https://www.barcelonanord.cat/en/services/passengers/), however if you only have small luggage (hand luggage size, so 55x40x25cm) then most restaurants won't have any problems if you take it with you (I have done this myself a number of times in different cities).

Other alternatives for leaving luggage are left luggage lockers at Barcelona Sants if you're staying in that area and are taking the train to the airport, or Locker Barcelona near Plaça de Catalunya (https://www.barcelona-tourist-guide.com/en/transport/locker-barcelona.html) - I haven't used their service so can't give a personal recommendation though. Google also gives various other options.

Comment: We're actually very close to Plaça de Catalunya so thanks for the great suggestion.